# Spring MVC unable to pick up Datasource configured in JNDI

Tags: tomcat, spring-mvc, jndi

I have a problem looking up DataSource using Spring 3.1 and JNDI look with Tomcat. It is not able to find the driver class for HSQL db even though I have provided the jar for it.

I have tried putting the jar in my Maven pom.xml as well copying the jar to ${CATALINA_HOME}/lib directory. But nothing seems to be working. My stack trace is given below.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'EProfileConfigureSimulator': 
Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Could not autowire method: public void com.myproject.simulator.ConfigureSimulator.setDataSource(javax.sql.DataSource); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}

Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost:9001/SIMULATORDB'

org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
. . . .
```

My Tomcat configuration in **$CATALINA_HOME/conf/context.xml**

```
<Resource name="jdbc/SimulatorDB" auth="Container"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource"
          driveClassName="org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver"
          url="jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost:9001/SIMULATORDB"
          username="SA" 
          password="" 
          initialSize="25"
          maxActive="100" 
          maxIdle="30"
          maxWait="10000" />
```

**web.xml**

```
<resource-ref>
      <description>HSQL Database</description>
      <res-ref-name>jdbc/SimulatorDB</res-ref-name> <!--  Must match the Server Resource name -->
      <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>  <!--  Must match the Server type  -->
      <res-auth>Container</res-auth> <!--  Must match the server auth attribute.  -->

    </resource-ref>
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```
        <!-- Enable annotations -->
<context:annotation-config />

  <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="java:comp/env/jdbc/SimulatorDB" expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource" />

<!--
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
  <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/SimulatorDB"/>
  <property name="lookupOnStartup" value="true"/>
  <property name="resourceRef" value="true" />
  <property name="expectedType" value="javax.sql.DataSource" />
  <property name="proxyInterface" value="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
</bean> -->
```

My source code

```
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

class JdbcHelper {
  private DataSource dataSource;

  @Autowired
  public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
     this.dataSource = dataSource;
  }

  public DataSource getDataSource() {
    return this.dataSource;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

`<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/SimulatorDB" expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource" />`

or

```
<bean id="dbDataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/SimulatorDB"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Should I use different names for either JndiObjectFactoryBean or when using jee:jndi bindings?

Comment: I finally discovered the cause of the error. I have not used "driverClassName" attribute in my tomcat configuration, but "driveClassName" (with a missing R). That caused the application to break.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the question author)*.

The issue was because I had misspelt the word **driverClassName**. I had included it without the "r". The application is successfully deployed now.